# How to add a New Row/Record for only 1 Table in a DataTable containing Records from 2 tables

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

How to Add a New Row/Record for only 1 Table in a DataTable containing Records from 2 tables

| CustomersTable... |
| --- |
| CustomerId |
| CustomerName |

| OrdersTable... |
| --- |
| OrdersId |
| CustomerId |
| OrderNumber |
| OrderDate |

```
string selectSql = "SELECT CustomersTable.CustomerName AS CustomersTable_CustomerName
, OrderTable.OrderNumber AS OrderTable_OrderNumber, 
OrderTable.OrderDate AS OrderTable_OrderDate 
FROM 
   CustomersTable 
INNER JOIN 
   OrdersTable 
ON (CustomersTable.CustomerId = OrdersTable.CustomerId) 
WHERE CustomersTable.CustomerId = 1"

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectSql);
da.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
DataTable dt;
da.Fill(dt);
```

In the DataTable we will get Records like this from Both the tables.

| CustomersTable_CustomerName | OrderTable_OrderNumber | OrderTable_OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 1001 | 01/01/2022 |
| Jack | 1002 | 02/01/2022 |

Now I know we can add Row by

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["OrderTable_OrderNumber"] = 1003;
dt.Rows.AddRow(dr);
string insertSql = "Insert ...in table...values.."
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql);
da.InsertCommand = insertCommand;
da.Update(dt);
```

But if we want to Add a Record Only in the OrdersTable, then How do we do it in the DataTable because DataTable has Columns from both the tables.

If we say Add New Row, then (I THINK) the Row gets added to CustomersTable also.

I hope this explains the question clearly. please let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must get two distinct DataTables. One for the "CustomersTable" and one for the "OrdersTable". From there, you must decide which of the tables you want to insert information for.

Your script to obtain the information is used to OBTAIN data from BOTH tables and you cannot insert information like this using DataTables as SqlDataAdapter...so you should only refer to the "OrdersTable" table.

P.S.: Honestly, if you can work with EF CodeFirst or EF DataBaseFirst with separate entities with classes and Interfaces properly structured with services to CRUD tables, you would not have these doubts and EF will arrange a lot of work for you.